# Definition of finite dimensional representation of a compact group

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, representation-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Consider the following fragment:

[image]

One asks that the map $\pi: G \to GL(V)$ is continuous. What does this mean? If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then we can view $GL(V)$ as matrices and then I guess it means that all the matrix entries are continuous?

What does continuity mean when $V$ is a Banach space (not necessarily finite-dimensional)? Which topology is put on $GL(V)$? Is it pointwise convergence topology?

Comment: $G$ is obviously a topological group, i.e. there is a topology already defined on it. We usually consider a norm induced topology on $GL(V)$, e.g. an operator norm if $V$ is a Banach space, or a matrix norm if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space without own topology. Continuity is then defined by these topologies.

Comment: When $V$ is a Banach, $GL(V)$ is an open subset of the Banach space $L(V)$ of continuous linear maps from $B$ to itself (with operator norm as its norm), so has the natural induced topology.

Comment: I think different topologies are suitable for different applications. If $V$ is a Hilbert space people often take the strong operator topology instead of the norm topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important representations of the additive group $\mathbb R$ takes place in the Hilbert space
$L^2(\mathbb R)$ and is given by
$$
\pi _s(\xi )|_t =  \xi (t-s), \quad \forall \xi \in L^2(\mathbb R),\ \forall t,s\in \mathbb R.
$$
This representation is not continuous with the norm topology on operators, but it is continuous with the strong
(i.e. pointwise) topology.  For that reason, most results about representations of topological groups assume strong continuity!

For a general locally compact group $G$,  there exists a left invariant measure $\mu $ on $G$ (called the Haar measure),  so we
may consider a similar  representation, this time  of $G$ on $L^2(G, \mu )$, given  by
$$
  \pi _s(\xi )|_t =  \xi (s^{-1}t), \quad \forall \xi \in L^2(G, \mu ),\ \forall t,s\in G.
  $$
Unless $G$ is discrete, this representation is not norm-continuous but again it is strongly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

To actually answer the question "What does continuity mean when $V$ is a Banach space" we need something stronger, that your text does not seem to mention:

We require that the group action of $G$ on $V$ defined by

$$G \times V \to V: (g, v) \mapsto \pi(g)v$$ is continuous. Here, $G \times V$ has the product topology.